# Is it possible to open urls in instagram’s browser outside of instagram app?

Tags: javascript, html, instagram

Is there exist a way to open some website in instagram browser clicking by url outside the instagram application.

Shortly, I want to open push users see mine website in instagram browser.

Thank you)

Comment: What do you mean by "instagram browser" ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.